# Parse FHIR Patient response to json

Tags: c#, asp.net, hl7-fhir

I'm new to .Net and FHIR. I followed a few tutorial to understand how FHIR API works. I need to create an application that use only GET request to get data from server. Below, I am trying to make a request to retrieve a patient by ID in PatientRepository class. However, when I test it with Postman, it doesn't return any response. How should I change my code? Many thanks

Model:

```
public class Patient : Hl7.Fhir.Model.Patient
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string birthday { get; set; }
    }

public class PatientList
    {
        public List<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```cs
public class PatientController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPatientRepository _patientRepository;
        public PatientController(IPatientRepository patientRepository)
        {
            _patientRepository = patientRepository;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/GetPatientById/{id}")]
        public IActionResult getPatientById(long id)
        {
            var model = _patientRepository.GetPatientById(id);
            if (model == null)
                return NotFound();
            return Ok(model);
        }
    }
}
```

PatientRepository:

```cs
public class PatientRepository : IPatientRepository
    {
        public async Task<Patient> GetPatientById(long id)
        {
            var client = new FhirClient("https://fhir.****.***/hapi-fhir-jpaserver/fhir/");
            client.Timeout = (60 * 100);
            client.PreferredFormat = ResourceFormat.Json;
            var pat = client.Read<Patient>("Patient/1");

            var parser = new FhirJsonParser();
            return new Patient
            {
                birthday = pat.birthday,
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see if your code is run and what code path it takes.

Comment: It would be good to change the name of your own Patient class, so you do not get confused with the FHIR Patient class later in your code.
I agree with Nick to use a debugger and set some breakpoints to step through your code and see what happens. If you request the FHIR Patient from the HAPI server with Postman, do you get a response?